Graph API isnt returning the column I need
I have a number of SharePoint sites that publish news articles. One of the Key fields is "First Published Date". Which shows if the article is published or still in draft.
I have tried;
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?$expand=fields

this returns most of the fields but the "First Published Date" is missing.
I have also tried
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/columns

Which returns all the columns for my list, including the one I want;
        {
        "columnGroup": "_Hidden",
        "description": "",
        "displayName": "First Published Date",
        "enforceUniqueValues": false,
        "hidden": false,
        "id": "c84f8697-331e-457d-884a-c4fb8f30ea74",
        "indexed": true,
        "name": "FirstPublishedDate",
        "readOnly": true,
        "required": false,
        "dateTime": {
            "displayAs": "default",
            "format": "dateTime"
        }
    },

Is there a way to return the value of this column in the first REST call?

Please check if this column is empty/null in your list or not.
